# Generic types that depend on another generic in Rust

Tags: generics, types, rust

I'm trying to create a struct that is generic, with a bound that the generic implement a trait. The trait is itself generic. This is in Rust 1.49.0.

If I do this:

```
trait Foo<T> {}

struct Baz<F: Foo<T>> {
    x: F,
}
```

I get a compilation error, because `T` is not defined. But if I define it:

```
trait Foo<T> {}

struct Baz<T, F: Foo<T>> {
    x: F,
}
```

then I get a compiler error because `T` is unused.

The only option seems to be to include a `PhantomData<T>` field, but if my generic dependence becomes more complicated, this starts to get more unwieldy:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait Foo<T> {}

struct Baz<T, U, F: Foo<T>, G: Foo<U>> {
    phantom_t: PhantomData<T>,
    phantom_u: PhantomData<U>,
    x: F,
    y: G,
}
```

Half of my fields are phantoms! The struct is practically haunted.

My question is: Is the example at the end that compiles really idiomatic Rust? And if so, why can Rust *not* detect that the `T` in `Baz<T, Foo<T>>` is actually used?

Comment: *Why* is it necessary that `F` implement `Foo<T>`, if it doesn't matter *which `T`* it implements it for? What if `F` implements both `Foo<i32>` and `Foo<u32>`, how will the choice of `T` make a difference to `Baz<F>`?

Comment: Well firstly I can't just do
`struct Baz<F: Foo<T>> { x: F}`
because I get a compiler error.

But in general I might want to constrain `T` with a bound. Or I might have a struct definition that looks like `Baz<F: Foo<T>, G: Foo<T>>`. I don't put any bounds on `T`, but `F` and `G` (which might be different) must implement `Foo<T>` for the *same* `T`.

Comment: `struct Baz<F> { x: F }` is what I meant. In any case, if you do go the `PhantomData` route it is important to know what kind of phantoms are haunting you. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the example at the end that compiles really idiomatic Rust?

The idiomatic way to store multiple phantom type parameters is with tuples:

```rust
struct Baz<T, U, F: Foo<T>, G: Foo<U>> {
    x: F,
    y: G,
    _t: PhantomData<(T, U)>,
}
```

> why can Rust not detect that the `T` in `Baz<T, Foo<T>>` is actually used?

This is actually intended behavior due to [variance](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0738-variance.md) and the [drop check](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/dropck.html). The idea here is that the compiler needs to know what constraints it can put on the type parameter `T`, and usage of the `PhantomData` type will instruct the compiler how it can do so.

You can learn more about `PhantomData` and how it affects variance in the [Rust nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/phantom-data.html).

Comment: Ah, very helpful. Thanks! When I make an instance of the struct is there anyway to avoid having to type out the `PhantomData`? i.e. can I somehow drop the last field in `Baz {x: foo1, y: foo2, _t: PhantomData}`?

Comment: @HarryBraviner no, you have to define it. But you could do something like `Baz {x: foo1, y: foo2, ...Self::default()}` if you derive `Default`

Comment: rustc does like `...`. It says: `expected identifier`.

Comment: @LukeSkywalker I missed the opening bracket, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably do one of these things:

1. If each struct `F` could implement `Foo` in several ways (`Foo<String>`, `Foo<i32>`, etc. for *the same* `F`), simply drop the bound from the struct `Baz`. The specific choice of `T` isn't relevant until you decide to use it, but attaching a bound forces you to pick a single `T` for which the struct will work, even if `F` would work with multiple types.

   Instead, put the `<T>` parameter and the `F: Foo<T>` bound only on the `impl` blocks where `T` is used (see [Should trait bounds be duplicated in struct and impl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49229332/3650362)).
2. If each struct `F` is expected to only implement `Foo` in one way, make `T` an associated type of `Foo` instead of a generic type. See [When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32059370/3650362)

You should *probably not* use `PhantomData<T>`. This marker type is used not just for variance, as Ibraheem's answer correctly mentions, but also by the [drop checker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42708462/3650362) to determine whether `Baz<T>` logically contains a `T`, and by the compiler to determine what [auto traits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49710852/3650362) should be implemented for `Baz<T>`. If you are not careful how you use it, you can accidentally overconstrain or underconstrain your API in subtle ways (see [Making a struct outlive a parameter given to a method of that struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62374326/3650362) for one example). Worse, because these properties of a type are visible externally, the choice of `PhantomData`'s type parameter can be exposed to external code, which makes fixing any mistake a breaking change.

If you don't know which of `PhantomData<T>`, `PhantomData<fn(T)>`, `PhantomData<fn() -> T>`, `PhantomData<fn(T) -> T>`, `PhantomData<*const T>` or `PhantomData<*mut T>` to use (six meaningfully distinct things, and this list is not exhaustive), you should read through the links above and try to determine which kind of variance, drop behavior and auto trait behavior `Baz` should have with respect to `T`. These are important qualities to know about a generic struct, and they are part of its external API. If any of them don't make sense for your use case, it probably means that `Baz` should not be generic over `T` at all.